# ffmpeg rename output if the file already exists

Tags: video, ffmpeg, cron

I am recording one hour long video clips from an rtsp stream through ffmpeg with a custom filename and I want it to check if the video file already exists each time it saves a clip to my hard drive and rename the new output to conserve both files.

For example if it is saving the clip `video-02222018.mp4` instead of overwriting it will rename it to `video-02222018-01.mp4` if the file already exists or `video-02222018-02.mp4` and so on as long as the file exists.

Note: I am going to run this using `crontab` on a `linux` system so it would fire this script each hour.

Comment: ffmpeg can't rename any files. But you can use the segment [muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) with a segment_time of 3600.

Comment: @Mulvya Would that work with an rtsp stream?

Comment: As input? I don't know your full command, but generally not a problem.

Comment: Yeah I am grabbing the clips from an rtsp stream. I will try it out and post back as soon as I get results.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, ffmpeg can't do this, as @Mulvya said. I'd suggest python script and using datetime to name your file so you will know which is most recent without having to search through all your files and increment.

outputFilename + '-' + timestamp